# How poorly have I implemented OAuth/OpenId?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid

I can't help but think I've implemented Open ID slightly incorrectly, but I also cannot find why I've done the implementation the way I have is bad or not.

Scenario:

Website - Used forms authentication before being updated to use OWIN.  Forms auth has been stripped out.

Website now supports OpenId to Okta.  This is being implemented for a large company of our users to facilitate their logins. This is functional.

The method I use for the site models how Microsoft does logins.  On email domain detection, we redirect the user to the login page for their domain.  In this case, Okta.  We receive the callback, and look up the user in our existing data, and generate a cookie based on our existing data (or create a new user account if they don't have one).
Essentially, just using Okta to confirm they are a valid user, and then we log them in with our user data.  We foresee doing this for other companies as well.

Problem:

I have a desktop (WPF) client that requires a login to our website.  This talks to API's that already exist using an auth key/token system we built many years ago.  Ideally, we do something similar.  Use Okta to verify the user is a user of that system, then generate a token that can be used for these API's.

Here is where I'm not sure I've done this appropriately.

The desktop client calls an API endpoint on our site with the email domain the user entered.  We verify the user's domain is allowed to use SSO, and if so, we issue back a challenge endpoint for the client to call.  This challenge endpoint is then called by the desktop client to launch the users default browser.

This challenge endpoint is an endpoint on OUR website, that essentially triggers the challenge to the IdP.  After login, a callback is called on OUR website, to process the auth response.  We verify the user's account is valid, and get the refresh token from the response.  With the refresh token, and an identifier of the user, this data is then sent back to the desktop client using localhost:randomPort so the client can consume the refresh token and identitifer. (Note that I do encrypt the refresh token and identifier's before returning them to the client)

This refresh token is then POSTed to OUR website, along with their identifier (so we can identify the IdP we should call), then use an OIDC client to verify the refresh token is still valid.  If the refresh token is still valid, we generate an app token and return it.

Is there a glaring issue with how this is implemented that I'm not seeing?  How can I do this differently?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the role of an Authorization Server (AS) that you own, to manage connections to other systems and to issue tokens to your apps.

You seem to have some good separation and to be doing quite a few things well - eg you are using your own tokens rather than foreign Okta tokens. The main issue is likely to be growing the system.

**PREFERRED BEHAVIOUR**

An AS should result in simpler code and a system that is easier to extend:

- You can add new authentication methods quickly
- This should involve just adding a connection (eg Okta) to your AS
- Doing so requires zero code changes in your UIs and APIs
- Your UIs just use standard OpenID Connect flows and call AS endpoints, regardless of the authentication method used
- Your APIs just verify tokens issued by the AS, then authorize requests, regardless of the authentication method used

Some scripting is needed in the AS, but typically this is small.

**FEATURES**

In terms of what an AS should do for you, have a browse of the [Curity Concepts Pages](https://curity.io/resources/learn/concepts-overview/). I work there, and we try to write about the science of OAuth and the common extensibility features software companies need.

**CHOOSING YOUR MOMENTS**

Integrating an AS and getting past all the blocking issues is a gradual journey though, and involves learning. So it requires choosing your moments, spikes and getting buy in from your stakeholders.

The main objective should always be simple and standard code in your apps, that is easy to scale. OAuth and the Authorization Server give you design patterns that help with this.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad to read that.  It is definitely something we have planned to do, but was trying to get something up and running without having to stand up another server at the moment.